# Tamaño Máximo JSON

Tags: asp.net, web.config

Vuelvo a activar esta pregunta por que quisiera saber si hay una forma de poner el maxJsonLength a indeterminado, ya que uso el máximo que me sugirieron en la respuesta pero mis datos sobrepasan ese tamaño.

"Recibo datos de una consulta SQL (más de 14000 registros), al usar el serializer para convertir mis datos a tabla se queda congelada mi aplicación web ya que el el tamaño de registros es muy grande. Modifiqué en mi webconfig el tamaño máximo con la siguiente etiqueta:

```
<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000"></jsonSerialization>
```

Ya funcionaba, pero el problema es que los datos incrementaron y se me volvió a quedar congelada la aplicación.

Alguien sabe el tamaño máximo para `maxJsonLenght`?? o alguna forma de ponerlo indeterminado por si tengo más datos? gracias!"

Comment: Ahh y tendría que pasarle el maxJsonLength vía parámetros??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El valor máximo que puedes asignarle es `2,147,483,647`(que es el valor maximo de Int32):

```
<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"></jsonSerialization>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, probé esa medida y al parecer funcionó, sólo que tarda mucho en realizar mi muestra de datos jajaja Gracias

Comment: Hola de nuevo, probé el número y funcionó pero el problema es que tengo más datos, hay alguna forma de ponerlo indeterminado?

Comment: Lamentablemente no. Ese es el limite.

Answer (score 0):

Igual dejo otra solución q les puede servir...

Luego de tomar la data asignada a una variable

> historico = histo.GetHistoricoFiltro(dateSince, dateUntil);
>   var JsonResult = Json(historico);

Luego esa variable le decimos a la propiedad MaxJsonLength de tipo Newtonsoft q acepte el valor máximo q es Int32 como esta en el comentario anterior.

> var JsonResult = Json(historico);
>   JsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

Un ejemplo completo...

> IEnumerable historico = null;   DataHistorico
>   histo = new DataHistorico();
>   historico = histo.GetHistoricoFiltro(dateSince, dateUntil);
>   var JsonResult = Json(historico);
>   JsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
>   return JsonResult;

Espero les sirva... ayuda de JSierra